# memory efficient prediction with randomForest in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, random-forest

***TL;DR***
I want to know memory efficient ways of performing a batch prediction with randomForest models built on large datasets (hundreds of features, 10's of thousands of rows).

**Details**:

I'm working with a large data-set (over 3GB, in memory) and want to do a simple binary classification using `randomForest`. Since my data is proprietary, I cannot share it, but lets say the following code runs

```
library(randomForest)
library(data.table)

myData <- fread("largeDataset.tsv")
myFeatures <- myData[, !c("response"), with = FALSE]
myResponse <- myData[["response"]]

toBePredicted <- fread("unlabeledData.tsv")

rfObj <- randomForest(x = myFeatures, y = myResponse, ntree = 100L)

predictedLabels <- predict(rfObj, toBePredicted)
```

However, it takes several GB of memory.

I know that I can save memory by turning off a bunch of proximity and importance measures and `keep.*` arguments:

```
rfObjWithPreds <- randomForest(x = myFeatures,
                               y = myResponse,
                               proximity = FALSE,
                               localImp = FALSE,
                               importance = FALSE,
                               ntree = 100L,
                               keep.forest = FALSE,
                               keep.inbag = FALSE,
                               xtest = toBePredicted)
```

However I'm now wondering whether this is the most memory efficient way of getting predictions for `toBePredicted`. Another way I could do this is by growing the forest in parallel and actively performing garbage collection:

```
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(ncores = 5)

subForestVotes <- foreach(subForestNumber = iter(seq.int(5)),
                          .combine = cbind) %dopar% {
    rfObjWithPreds <- randomForest(x = myFeatures,
                               y = myResponse,
                               proximity = FALSE,
                               localImp = FALSE,
                               importance = FALSE,
                               ntree = 100L,
                               keep.forest = FALSE,
                               keep.inbag = FALSE,
                               xtest = toBePredicted)
   output <- rfObjWithPreds[["test"]][["votes"]]
   rm(rfObjWithPreds)
   return(output)
}
```

Does anyone have a smarter way of efficiently predicting `toBePredicted`?

Comment: Have you looked at the bigrf package http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigrf/index.html ?

Comment: I have not, I will check it out, though.

Comment: Can you answer your own question?

Comment: Sorry, I sort of let this thing drop. I'm a bit too busy to properly investigate and/or answer this question.

Comment: There are streaming random-forest processes.  They might be able to make a streaming prediction.